# item list max capacity at 5000: anybody know what happens at 5001?

Tags: sharepoint-online, limitations

In a scenario of a simple document library with standard view, standard paging, what happens practically when you reach 5001 items? (sharepoint on line)

Comment: You won't be able to filter/sort items in views, unless you index the columns used in the view. You also won't be able to link another list to it using lookup columns. Have a look at [this article](https://en.share-gate.com/blog/demystifying-the-sharepoint-list-thresholds)

Answer (score 0):

The view supports 5000 items. This is the number of items sql will allow you to view at a time. Nothing will go wrong if you did not have all the 5000 items listed directly and not under any folder.

On the contrary if you were to write a web app and try to access the library items, it will throw an error. You can get over it by indexing the items. Also, in that case you should be aware that you are also not performing search with more than 5000 results in your app.

There are a lot of different answers to your question but the 5000 limit is not a plague that you need to avoid if you are okay living with some limitations.